# imagerotate changes original image's color

Tags: php, gd, php-imagine, wideimage

I am encountering a very strange behavior when rotating images with PHP.  The original image is being changed during the rotation.  As an example, here are the side by side images. It's hard to see, but if you look closely, the white area surrounding the knife is being changed from #FFFFFF to #FDFDFD.

[image]

I am using imagerotate with no options specified, however, if I try the same thing with a black background color, I get a rotated image with black "fill", but the white part of the image is still changed from #FFFFFF to #FDFDFD.  I am baffled. It's almost like PHP is "rounding" the colors.

[image]

original image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cK6mg.jpg

### rotated image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1413E.jpg

edit:

here's my code

```
$img = imagecreatefromjpeg($localFile);
$img = imagerotate($img, 45, 0);
imagejpeg($img, '/tmp/a.jpg');
```

Comment: Can you post a imgur link to the original image and the code you're using to rotate? I'd like to see if I get the same results.

Comment: original image: http://i.imgur.com/iYwvxAE.jpg rotated image: http://i.imgur.com/0lXXuO6.jpg

Comment: Out of curiousity, if you try the same thing with PNG do you get the same results?

Comment: same results rotating a PNG and saving to JPG.  I haven't tried saving to PNG though.

Comment: I'd be curious if saving to PNG doesn't have the issue, that being said, one possible solution (but not necessarily a great one) would be to find the #fdfdfd and replace it with #ffffff. `$index = imagecolorclosest ($im,  253, 253, 253); imagecolorset($im, $index, 255, 255, 255);`

Comment: I tried saving to PNG and had the same issue.

Comment: were you able to reproduce with the original images?

Comment: Not yet, could you post the code you're using? Which version of gd are you using? You can use this to find out: `var_dump(gd_info());`

Comment: 2.1.1 with PHP 5.6.6

Comment: I just updated my question with the code

Comment: I am having the exact same problem using your example image. Give me a few minutes to play around with this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got it! On the php doc for imagerotate (http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagerotate.php) I noticed

> "Note: This function is affected by the interpolation method set by imagesetinterpolation()."

I then tried a few different interpolation algorithms. IMG_BELL seems to maintain white.

```
<?php
function LoadJpeg($imgname)
{
    $im = imagecreatefromjpeg($imgname);
    imagesetinterpolation($im, IMG_BELL);
    $im = imagerotate($im, 45, 0);
    return $im;
}

$img = LoadJpeg('test.jpg');

imagejpeg($img, 'C:\temp\a.jpg', 100);
imagedestroy($img);
```

Comment: i seem to be getting better results using IMG_BICUBIC but thanks for pointing me in the right direction, this solves the problem.

Comment: In my case it destroy some text color and form